Как исправить погрешность при рассчете процентов в сетке
Я делаю сетку, где между линиями расстояние в пррцентах. Всего 50 линий, и на 1 линии 0.5%, то на последней 0.4%, т.е погрешность. Куда делись 0.1% и какую формулу использовать
tt =""
dc = str.length(str.tostring(syminfo.mintick)) - 2

for i = 1 to dc
    tt +=   "#"

ng = 50
ar = array.new<float>()
pe = input.float(0.5, "%")
cl = color.new(color.blue, 50)
bp = input.price(0, "~", confirm = true)

for i = 0 to ng
    pr = str.tonumber(str.format("{0, number, #." + tt + "}", bp + (i * (bp / 100 * pe))))
    line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1 = pr, x2 = bar_index, y2 = pr, style = line.style_dotted, color = cl, extend = extend.both)
    array.push(ar, pr)


Всего 50 линий, и на 1 линии 0.5%, то на последней 0.4% вот это бы стоило расшифровать

@mBo рисуются на графике снизу вверх линии с 1 по 50. 1 линия в сетке от линии к линии 0.5% (по высоте), далее идут линии 2 3 4 ... 50. И с каждой новой линии по чуть чуть куда-то деваются проценты. И на последней 50 линии высота 0.4%.

Преобразование в строку, а потом в число - это такое округление? В этом не может быть дело? Если просто посмотреть на числа, вычисленные bp + (i * (bp / 100 * pe)) - между ними тоже разница меняется?

@mBo оставил только вычисление и погрешность осталась. Вообще преобразование в строку и потом в число мне необходимо для обрезания чисел после точки до длины как у выбранного актива, и далее они идут в массив для других дел. А вот последний вопрос не понял. Естественно между ними есть разница, ведь шаг 0.5%. Или что имеется ввиду .. ?

Ну если без обрезания шаг (разница между соседними) точно одинаковый, а после обрезания разный - значит, дело в этом обрезании.

@mBo я этого не говорил. Я сказал что оставил только вычисления (без обрезания) и погрешность осталась

Язык ваш редкий. Может, деление  для целых выполняется не так, как вы ожидаете, или ещё что экзотическое? Вот на Python можно увидеть, что разница сохраняется.

@mBo согласен. Я работаю js или php, а данный скрипт заказал у програмиста, который не смог сделать и часть ТЗ, поэтому взял в свои руки кодинг и гугл. Сделал всё и даже уведомления, но вопрос погрешности решить не могу

Ну тут, наверное, только смотреть, что на каждом этапе получается. (bp / 100 * pe) - константа, а при умножении на разные i или при сложении результата с bp, может, что-то случается.
